# Alea GPU Compiler directives like "__unroll"?

Tags: aleagpu

Just discovered Alea.Gpu and am very pleased with its simplicity of use and C# integration.

However I was just wondering if compiler directives such as "__unroll" are available somewhere? It seems that it used to be available in the Alea.CUDA package which seems deprecated.

Any tips ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this directive works only for F# quotation based code. It provides kernel as a F# quotation. C# coded kernel is not supported.

For more information on using AleaGPU in F#, see http://www.aleagpu.com/release/3_0_3/doc/advanced_features_fsharp.html

Comment: Thanks, hope it will be integrated in C# eventually.